# how to correctly echo the href in php with value on it?

Tags: php, html

my echo shows unexpected T_VARIABLE and i dont know how to correctly echo my href please help me

```
echo '<a href="'.edit_account.php?id=$val['id'].'"  class="btn btn-xs btn-info">Edit</a>'
```

please help me im a beginner

Comment: you just missed  the terminal semicolon  `;`

Comment: I would recommend to use spaces around your concatenation operator `.`. You could then spot mistakes easier.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Replace

```
'<a href="'.edit_account.php?id=$val['id'].'"  class="btn btn-xs btn-info">Edit</a>'
```

with

```
'<a href="edit_account.php?id='.$val['id'].'"  class="btn btn-xs btn-info">Edit</a>'
```

You started concatenation from the wrong place

Answer (score 0):

You have incorrect use of string concatenation. Also, better use double quotes when forming the link so that you wouldn't need separate concatenation for PHP variables.

```
<?php

echo "<a href='/edit_account.php?id=$val[id]'  class='btn btn-xs btn-info'>Edit</a>";
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe the code should look something like this

```
<a href="<?php echo $your_url_variable?>" > your anchor text here </a>
```

or

```
echo '<a href="'.$your_url_variable.'">';
```

depending on where you want to insert the url

Comment: This is not what the question is about. This looks more like a suggestion which should be in a comment.